# CUDA texture interpolation incorrect for normalized co-ordinates

Tags: cuda, textures, interpolation

I am trying to use CUDA texture interpolation on a lookup table of floats. When normalized co-ordinates are used the results are incorrect; when non-normalized co-ordinates are used, they are correct. Why is this?

Compilable example:

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>

texture<float, cudaTextureType1D, cudaReadModeElementType> table_tex;

const int N_table = 6;

// y = 2*x for x in [0, 1)
float table[N_table] = {0, 0.4, 0.8, 1.2, 1.6, 2.0};

__global__ void hw_linear_interpolation(const float* inputs,
                                        float* interpolated,
                                        const unsigned int n_inputs)
{
    int tid = threadIdx.x;

    if (tid < n_inputs)
    {
        float val = inputs[tid];

#ifdef NORMALIZED
        float interp = tex1D(table_tex, val);
#else
        float interp = tex1D(table_tex, (N_table-1)*val+0.5f);
#endif
        interpolated[tid] = interp;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int N_inputs = 11;

    thrust::host_vector<float> h_inputs(N_inputs);
    thrust::device_vector<float> d_outputs(N_inputs);
    thrust::host_vector<float> h_outputs(N_inputs);

    // Allocate CUDA array in device memory to bind table_tex to.
    cudaChannelFormatDesc channelDesc =
                             cudaCreateChannelDesc<float>();
    cudaArray* cuArray_table;
    cudaMallocArray(&cuArray_table, &channelDesc, N_table, 0);

    // Copy to device memory some data located at address h_data
    // in host memory
    cudaMemcpyToArray(cuArray_table, 0, 0, table, N_table*sizeof(float),
                      cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    // Initialize input values to interpolate from the table for.
    for (int i=0; i<N_inputs; i++) {
        h_inputs[i] = i*0.1f;
    }

    thrust::device_vector<float> d_inputs = h_inputs;

    // Set up texture for linear interpolation with normalized inputs.
    table_tex.addressMode[0] = cudaAddressModeClamp;
    table_tex.filterMode = cudaFilterModeLinear;
#ifdef NORMALIZED
    table_tex.normalized = true;
#else
    table_tex.normalized = false;
#endif

    cudaBindTextureToArray(table_tex, cuArray_table);
    hw_linear_interpolation<<<1, 128>>>(
        thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_inputs.data()),
        thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_outputs.data()),
        N_inputs);
    cudaUnbindTexture(table_tex);
    h_outputs = d_outputs;

    std::cout << "     x     |   interp. y   |   actual y  ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "-----------------------------------------";
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout.setf(std::ios::fixed, std::ios::floatfield);
    for (int i=0; i<N_inputs; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "    ";
        std::cout.precision(1);
        std::cout.width(3);
        std::cout << h_inputs[i];
        std::cout << "    |";

        std::cout << "    ";
        std::cout.precision(5);
        std::cout.width(7);
        std::cout << h_outputs[i];
        std::cout << "    |";

        std::cout << "   ";
        std::cout.width(7);
        std::cout << 2*(i*0.1f);
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling as `nvcc -arch=sm_20 interpolation_so.cu` gives

```
$ ./a.out 
     x     |   interp. y   |   actual y  
-----------------------------------------
    0.0    |    0.00000    |   0.00000
    0.1    |    0.20000    |   0.20000
    0.2    |    0.40000    |   0.40000
    0.3    |    0.60000    |   0.60000
    0.4    |    0.80000    |   0.80000
    0.5    |    1.00000    |   1.00000
    0.6    |    1.20000    |   1.20000
    0.7    |    1.40000    |   1.40000
    0.8    |    1.60000    |   1.60000
    0.9    |    1.80000    |   1.80000
    1.0    |    2.00000    |   2.00000
```

but compiling as `nvcc -arch=sm_20 interpolation_so.cu -DNORMALIZED` gives

```
$ ./a.out
     x     |   interp. y   |   actual y  
-----------------------------------------
    0.0    |    0.00000    |   0.00000
    0.1    |    0.04063    |   0.20000
    0.2    |    0.27969    |   0.40000
    0.3    |    0.52031    |   0.60000
    0.4    |    0.75938    |   0.80000
    0.5    |    1.00000    |   1.00000
    0.6    |    1.24063    |   1.20000
    0.7    |    1.47969    |   1.40000
    0.8    |    1.72031    |   1.60000
    0.9    |    1.95938    |   1.80000
    1.0    |    2.00000    |   2.00000
```

Edit: partial fix based on [Dithermaster's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24790934/927046)

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're adding 0.5 here:`tex1D(table_tex, val+0.5f);`
Normalized coordinates go from 0.0 to 1.0 so adding 0.5 offsets by a full half of your range.

Comment: Yes, this is an issue in the posted code, but there's more to it than that.  Making this change in the code does not completely "fix" it.

Comment: But it should get you a lot closer. Probably the next issue is that the values are "slightly" off because the half-pixel interval from 0.0 to the center of the first pixel is constant, and the same on the other end (center of last pixel to 1.0). This is why 0.5 is added in the non-normalized case. See http://www.eecg.toronto.edu/~moshovos/CUDA08/slides/008%20-%20Textures.ppt

Comment: ...in particular slide 13, but also the slides that lead up to it so you understand what it is showing.

Comment: Thanks. Question updated. I did wonder about that, but misunderstood the description in http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#linear-filtering as applying to normalized co-ordinates as well (which obviously does not make sense). But I can't work out what needs to be added in the normalized case, if it is actually possible to achieve what I want...?

Comment: Try this: `float interp = tex1D(table_tex, (((n_table-1)/(float)n_table))*(val+0.1f));`

Comment: Aha! That's it, and it makes sense to me. Thanks. Although after all that, I think it's probably simpler to stick to non-normalized co-ordinates for my application.